# NAN when I use ReLU activation function in convolutional neural network Lenet-5

Tags: neural-network, convolution, backpropagation

I did programmed convolution neural network LeNet-5. I made some modifications:

1. I replaced the activation function of output neurons in the last layer RBF to SoftMah.
2. SubSampling layers to MaxPooling layers.
3. Learning method is Backpropagation

As a result, the network is working correctly.

After that I tried to replace the sigmoid output of each neuron in the feature maps to ReLU (Rectifier Linear Unit). As a result, the network began to learn faster, but if I do not choose a low speed, I get NaN value.

For a small set of input data, it is simpler to use a lower speed of learning. When it comes to more than 1,000 examples, the network is working, but in the end I get NaN again.

Why is there a NaN when using ReLU? Is LeNet architecture is not for ReLU?

Comment: What software / language is this question?  Could you show your example?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I have fixed English issues with your post.  I also fixed the bullets to work.

Comment: Getting NaNs is purely an implementation issue so it's not really possible to tell without seeing code. Most likely some value has converged to 0 and you're dividing by it. First suspect is the gradient (take this as a very wild guess). So basically debug and observe values to find out where the values explode/vanish.